# Javascript: adding more flexibility to my arrays, such as inserting html code in the middle of array options?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, syntax

So here's my script:

```
function getRandomArrayIndex(source_array) {

return Math.floor(Math.random() * source_array.length);

}

function getRandomArrayEntry(source_array) {

var random_index = getRandomArrayIndex(source_array);

return source_array[random_index];

}

function getRandomV5test() {

var v5tests = [
["This should tell me I have the following amount of minutes: "],
["This is the number of times I want to jump up and down: "],
["This is a quote."],
]; var random_v5test = getRandomArrayEntry(v5tests);

return random_v5test;

}

function displayV5test(v5test) {
    var element = document.getElementById("v5test");
    if(element !== null){
        var TEXT_ROW = 0;
        var LINK_ROW = 1;
        var v5test_text = v5test[TEXT_ROW];
        var v5test_link = v5test[LINK_ROW]; 
        if (v5test_link != null) {
            element.innerHTML = '<a href="' + v5test_link + '">' + v5test_text + '</a>';
        } else {
            element.innerHTML = v5test_text + '<span id="time"></span>';
        }
    }
}

function generateRandomV5test(){

var random_v5test = getRandomV5test();

displayV5test(random_v5test);

}
```

What this does is, in combination with multiple sibling scripts, generates a phrase with a random outcome. It runs before other scripts which insert *their* random phrase into the span id specified ('time'), and the end result on a page might be something along the lines of:

> This should tell me I have the following amount of minutes: 40

The problem is that this gives me no flexibility - the span I specify after 'v5test_text' must always come afterwards. In addition, the third array option would still return a random number regardless of what array option was chosen by the script, looking like this:

> This is a quote. 25

What I want to be able to do is put the html code inside different array options, like the following:

```
var v5tests = [
["This should tell me I have <span id="time"></span> minutes. "],
["I want to jump up and down <span id="time"></span> times. "],
["This is a quote."],
```

So, really it's a simple question. **What syntax do I use if I want to prevent html code used in this instance being confused by the script itself?** Knowing this will give me almost unlimited flexibility in terms of the content of my website.

Any help would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: You could have included the last 4 sentences and your last code sample and avoided a lot of confusion.

Comment: I agree, though being very new to programming I'm not really aware of what problems will be understood, or whether they require a use-case to help people understand what I'm trying to do in real terms. Plus I suppose it might help others in similar situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes to define your strings...

```
var v5tests = [
['This should tell me I have <span id="time"></span> minutes.'],
['I want to jump up and down <span id="time"></span> times.'],
['This is a quote.'],
```

Or Escape your double quotes inside the strings:

```
var v5tests = [
["This should tell me I have <span id=\"time\"></span> minutes. "],
["I want to jump up and down <span id=\"time\"></span> times. "],
["This is a quote."],
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I chose the first option. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes, once the cooldown finishes. :D

Comment: @user1548172 I prefer to use single quotes when I can to define strings because I prefer (and is more common) to use double quotes in my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to escape your quotation marks with the backslash escape character.

```
var v5tests = [
    "This should tell me I have <span id=\"time\"></span> minutes.",
    "I want to jump up and down <span id=\"time\"></span> times. ",
    "This is a quote."
];
```